# Loop array inside an array and remove key with its value in php

Tags: php

I have an array in the below format.

```
array (
0 => 
array (
'safe_route' => 'yes',
'route_name' => 'route_1',
'route_risk_score' => '2.5'),
 1 =>
array (
'safe_route' => 'no',
'route_name' => 'route_2',
'route_risk_score' => '3.5'),
 2 =>
array (
'safe_route' => 'no',
'route_name' => 'route_3',
'route_risk_score' => '4.5')
)
```

i need to loop it and remove the key 'route_risk_score' with its value inside all arrays. How this can be done in php. Am new to php.Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To delete element in original array, use a **reference** to each element:

```
// see this & in front of `$item`? 
// It means that `$item` is a reference to element in original array 
// and unset will remove key in element of original array, not in copy
foreach($array as &$item) {          
    unset($item['route_risk_score']);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$data = array(
0 =>array(
    'safe_route' => 'yes',
    'route_name' => 'route_1',
    'route_risk_score' => '2.5'),
1 =>array(
    'safe_route' => 'no',
    'route_name' => 'route_2',
    'route_risk_score' => '3.5'),
2 =>array(
    'safe_route' => 'no',
    'route_name' => 'route_3',
    'route_risk_score' => '4.5')
);
$count = count($data);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
     unset($data[$i]['route_risk_score']);
}
echo'<pre>';print_r($data);die;
output :
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [safe_route] => yes
        [route_name] => route_1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [safe_route] => no
        [route_name] => route_2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [safe_route] => no
        [route_name] => route_3
    )

)
```